# Generic class transformation in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm working on a project where I need to instantiate multiple copies of a particular class, but with different parameters. I'm creating a utility function `withAlteredConstructorArgs` to help me with this, but I'm having trouble getting the types quite right.

Here is an example of how I would like to use this utility:

```js
const createCycler = withAlteredConstructorArgs(
  Cycler,
  function reverseElementArgs<T>(elements: Array<T>): [Array<T>] {
    return [elements.reverse()];
  }
);

const cycler = createCycler(['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'quux']);

console.log(cycler.get(), cycler.get());
// > should log 'quux', 'baz'
```

The function I've written works as intended, but does not typecheck the way I expected. I have created a [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-sY5WOdX4Vp+YPwbW8PXX4QVITXsA4DgV4FFedpLGAxBQJEAAvCDXgARxAEBuFeJlOVqSg4FFUxsDgJgVAgb8CFMd19gUQjGxIvAPTsDkgA) to fully demonstrate, but here is the implementation:

```js
function withAlteredConstructorArgs<Args extends Array<any>, T>(
  c: { new(...args: Args): T },
  fn: (...args: Args) => Args
): (...args: Args) => T {
  return (...args: Args) => new c(...fn(...args))
}
```

I recognize that I am not constraining `T` enough, and that's why I'm getting the error message: `'any[]' is assignable to the constraint of type 'Elements', but 'Elements' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'any[]'`. **I understand this error and have fixed it before**, but not in a problem relating to class constructor arguments. **What is the correct syntax for properly constraining the constructor parameters for `T`?**

I recognize that I could probably work around this by creating a factory function and removing constructors altogether from the problem statement, but I feel as though understanding this approach would better improve my understanding of TypeScript in general. Also, I have hit [similar issues](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-COvLk4gIEQ7Sq1QQ0agMDh8EQyCYzM59IY6ZGYmAyYgJ9qCOuXIFDKBILAED28BtCEw8KGg84WKpdK3w8GTSJH5IEoh2UIP0-eStRNeyQdkXwjawiCvAgbzuYsB1lIdkRTCBVT3NFRzwcc0MIHR2RBYA4DgEFZBBUZ7BIxAyPIAAvSiQQARxAEAuBBcU5W6eY4G1axsDgWlUMnaxYzuWRBL3YTFDuWUgA) with the factory approach, so it seems as though the constructor method would be the way to go anyways.

Comment: Interesting question. What's the motivation for having `withAlteredConstructorArgs` call the constructor for you? Would `const cycler = new Cycler(reverseElementArgs(['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'quux']));
` have the same effect?

Comment: I'd love to just call it directly, but this is a service manager that will be iterating over a list and creating a new service instance for each config in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the correct syntax for properly constraining the constructor parameters for `T`?

I thought I understood your question based on the code you've written *until* I read *that*, which makes me less sure about which argument you would like to be the provider of the type information creating the constraint and which argument you'd like to be constrained.

I'm going to respond based on how you wrote your code: that you want the parameters of the constructor provided as the *first* argument to provide the type information for `Args`, and for the callback function to take arguments of that type.

A potential point of confusion could be multidimensional arrays: the `Args` are an array of arguments, **and** your class constructor for `Cycler` accepts an array as its **first and only** argument (so, an array within an array).

Another potential point of confusion here is that you seem to want higher-kinded types, but [that's not available in TypeScript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) (yet, at least). It seems like you want `createCycler` to be generic (it isn't in your example), and you can make it generic by using a generic type assertion on it. (In other cases, you could use a generic type *annotation*, but I don't think that will work here.)

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=68&ssc=57&pln=1&pc=1#code/PTAEBEFMDMEsDtKgC4AsnQK7wMbNgPbwBcAUKcgJ4AOSAYvADymigAKAhgE4cC2AzqEgAPZJHgATQdgDW8AgHd4AbQC6oALygO8SmoA0LUACVI-TABtkm7bsMA+GwAoAdG+rc+-Yu08CAlJqOpuZWANzkVLSgAMLIBFzMrJw8AkKi4lKgsvJKajY6eqqGrCGW1lqFDjaICqCu7n7evqn8gRrBZuURIKCOWgDeoLX1bi4erT4pXv4+ZVagAL5hoL0Aggv8lPDIHMLkWLj4RKAKsGgbYlyQEjFE-MhcmHgJa1wA5vyMMelikoJxBL2JxGF5cHwxEqgaAkUAMb73R7PeJcaa8SBXL4xez6WKIp5gtEYyBcLH2HGkWZwph3eAPAkoomY7440AASTpu1wkAAKjRICzHAMjNdkJguPBRm5uJ8IfjkQkmSSye1HCMwQ0XDDNTK2v4IotyL0AKr8SBkUi9OiwUnIXE6dJ8agWJCYfgId7aUDu3jOkmgHAWDj8QQKVCwHCoCAAeQAogBlAByAHIeSgODIkBxQO9xCSI9ouDxKJawDoJCh0JK3UhztpBGgkFEMAlQOdBHBbQH5WDQBM+MTwaRA8HBGxlSdhawcD2UfVrhwJEQLJRoTaHj56R7cQul-AV6AgxvvY8PYEBobWBYCJ6nOejNP7gQXS5r+8nGhYPwteu7ZWv6+wbIPqRiGoaw6IgGC5iOOpInFoZwXFYJI3LS9IKlwbyfCCyQTvAUI4awa62rivQzkWkB4AeCDQCS1wVsGJ5cB6D6HkBpFlu8HAILiW7wO8RiqqAyisZ2DwuPEAAyigkjEwaQHeUJXkBEkEMa1C0FwclmneRjqIxyh8e8vGnvxxSrGAPLxqAS5mPAybWDR-pin6-C8QQtj1maXDHJKX7DJANw3KA6DXJSEQQZyfY2Dg0GQLB-BEE4yYAOrPtAXH8cmuLJgAsgQABe3DIMmIHUK+N53hZoAAEQKOlmXvDVtW5dGABaazGDyNVGmAiaKLilAEOKsSUIG-ojiGFqTQCY0uoksYuuiOyCCIfxZG8xaMIU5KgFOfbMQAbhwYhtpIIg2AADBEj6cgyCRONQR0nUgkBLeIyDNItkDLZ956XjmGJVftt0PEIFg2J+35vT9H38MoUMuAgEgiKoN1EQA1BjiPIyI6OsDj53CKAACkWiIzDv3fi6-FoKxoripKb2gaQ4G9GyZ20RRFZoCdoBDZgpw6NYUMoB5ABGSC5ogzE4GQvSJZWfONig-KCAQ0CVlmHyYFTfajsF8Ra9C2B4IQkq8451jGLGPLGsYibxqWpywBYEOS9kZoVtArYq9coT4Pxo3jVwZ0PDoOCQJFYOxZAL0xHN-oIecqCXChtyzq8Hz8IRCchwRlNw0JyiFytLjXIdyoKf4+mCMoOSKCoqjFJS9agIwaZrZkgiFGowKl59Pg8kJefzR39gRTOUU4InodaLH8ez04yjJj7BDZaAybi9wG9bxwBW7wAjpgmDCMmqj6tVo8kowRl99Hz6QBV74zyHLi5sgikBrP79A-4l+9BqsfU+zUarbwKj1IAA)

```ts
// Define the function:

type Fn<
  Params extends unknown[] = any[],
  Result = any,
> = (...params: Params) => Result;

type Ctor<
  Params extends unknown[] = any[],
  Result = any,
> = new (...params: Params) => Result;
// > = { new (...params: Params): Result }; // Alt syntax

function withAlteredConstructorArgs<C extends Ctor>(
  ctor: C,
  fn: Fn<ConstructorParameters<C>, ConstructorParameters<C>>,
): Fn<ConstructorParameters<C>, InstanceType<C>> {
  return (...args: ConstructorParameters<C>) => new ctor(...fn(...args));
}

// Use:

// First, an example using a simpler class which DOESN'T take a generic array
// and then use it as the type for its first constructor parameter:
class Person {
  constructor (readonly first: string, readonly last: string) {}
  log () {
    console.log(this.first, this.last);
  }
}

const createPerson = withAlteredConstructorArgs(
  Person,
  (
    first, // correctly inferred as string
    last, // again, string
  ) => [
    first.toLowerCase(),
    last.toUpperCase()
  ] as [string, string], // TS doesn't infer tuples, so an assertion is needed here
);

const p = createPerson('Wolfgang', 'Mozart');
p.log() // "wolfgang" "MOZART"

// Now, your Cycler class:

class Cycler<Elements extends Array<any>> {
  private index = 0;
  constructor(private elements: Elements) {}
  get() {
    const el = this.elements[this.index];
    ++this.index;
    this.index %= this.elements.length
    return el
  }
}

// I inferred that you want this to be generic:
// so that the types of the arguments passed to the function that it RETURNS
// will be used for the resulting Cycler instance
const createCycler = withAlteredConstructorArgs(
  Cycler,
  (elements) => [elements.reverse()] as [unknown[]],
) as <T extends any[]>(elements: T) => Cycler<T>;

const cycler = createCycler(['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'quux']); // Cycler<string[]>
console.log(cycler.get(), cycler.get()); // "quux" "baz"
```

Comment: The way you broke out `Ctor` was exactly what I was missing -- thank you! My Cycler example was a bad one since it introduced additional complexity; thank you for creating the `Person` example since it's a better illustration.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get your code to compile and produce the expected output with the following changes:

- Changing the definition of `Cycler` from `class Cycler<Elements extends Array<any>>` to `class Cycler<E>`.
- Changing the signature of `Cycler`'s constructor from `constructor(private elements: Elements)` to `constructor(private elements: E[])`.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-KIJMoicJxGPyXo0xmkISJ67TERewR+-tfdmObmbRB+c3wRAC-gm4QVITXsA4HBXgpXu1LK-EO+RAAvL+vAAjiAIDcK8TKcrUlBwNqSZwEwKhnsWpjmvsChIc2KF4BadgckAA)

Comment: Currently `Cycler.elements` can be a heterogeneous tuple, but you're suggesting a change which restricts it to a homogeneous array.

Comment: Couldn't `E[]` also be heterogeneous if `E` was a union type? I guess there's a gap in my understanding here.

Comment: Homogeneous in the sense that each item must be of the same type (which could be a union, of course)

Comment: I think this demonstrates why my suggestion does not support the same cases as the original: https://tsplay.dev/W4yROw

Comment: That's both a minimal and clear demonstration, I think!